# Did they remove the number of emails in a folder from the toolbar in Yosemite's Mail.app?

Tags: mail.app, email, macos

Before I upgraded to Yosemite, I used to see the number of unread and total emails in a folder in the title/header bar,  e.g.

**Inbox (23) 64 messages**

I no longer see this - is there any way of getting it back?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is : No.

Here is a screen of my Yosemite's Mail.app

[image]

Did you tried restarting it ?

Comment: Restarting didn't help, so must be something corrupt with my OS/app/config.

Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a bug and has been reported to Apple.

A discussion on the Apple forums mentions this same problem, [OS X Yosemite mail stopped showing total inbox message count](http://discussions.apple.com/thread/6617368):

> This appears to be a bug. It is triggered when you view a smart folder - once you do, the count in the title bar will disappear until you restart mail.
>
> I filed this as a bug with Apple, so they're aware of it. No ETA for a fix though.